# Dynamic protobuf messages in protobuf-net

Tags: c#, c++, protobuf-net

I'm building plugin architecture. Users can build own plugins and I allowing them to put their own plugin settings in `protobuf` (I don't know what type users will put there).

Protos messages:

```
message pbPlugin{
    required string id = 1; 
    required string type = 2;
    optional bytes settings = 3;
    optional bytes settings_descriptor= 4;
}

message pbMyPluginSetting{
    optional double exposure=1;
    optional int32 pixel_clock=2;
}
```

Server side (c++):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
pbPlugin* pb_plugin;

pbMyPluginSetting plugin_settings; //it's user class i don't know it
plugin_settings.set_exposure(7);
plugin_settings.set_pixel_clock(28);

void *plugin_settings_buffer = malloc(plugin_settings.ByteSize());
plugin_settings.SerializeToArray(plugin_settings_buffer , plugin_settings.ByteSize());

pbPlugin->set_settings(plugin_settings_buffer , plugin_settings.ByteSize());

const Descriptor* desc=plugin_settings.GetDescriptor();
void *plugin_settings_desc_buffer = malloc(desc.ByteSize());
plugin_settings.SerializeToArray(plugin_settings_desc_buffer , desc.ByteSize());

pbPlugin->settings_descriptor(plugin_settings_desc_buffer , desc.ByteSize());
}
```

So user is making his own `protobuf` message and he is serializing it and he is putting it in setting filed of `pbPlugin` message and also he is serializing this message descriptor.

Now on client side (c# application) I'm getting back my `pbPlugin` message and i want to deserialize setting field, and change exposure and `pixel_clock`. My problem is that don't know how I can I deserialize message without knowing its type? Is it possible in `protobuf-net`?

In c++ I would use descriptor I've serialized and `DynamicMessageFactory` to create message to put deserialized settings in.

```
DynamicMessageFactory dmf;
Message* actual_msg = dmf.GetPrototype(deserialized_descriptor)->New();
```

This way I can access and change fields values.
How could I achieve it it `protobuf-net`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I've found solution to this problem. Sadly it seems to not be possible with protobuf-net but it's quite easy with protobuf-sharp-port. I've replace library and from there yo can access file descriptor like this.

-get file descriptor:

```
global::Google.ProtocolBuffers.DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto fdp= global::Google.ProtocolBuffers.DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto.ParseFrom(settings_descriptors);
```

-get message descriptor:

```
global::Google.ProtocolBuffers.Descriptors.MessageDescriptor descriptor= fdp.MessageTypes[0];
```

and from there you can get dynamic message:

```
Google.ProtocolBuffers.DynamicMessage dynamic_message = Google.ProtocolBuffers.DynamicMessage.GetDefaultInstance(descriptor);
```

Hope it will help someone with same problem.